# Merge additional nodes to Stripe token before passing it to the Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, stripe-payments

I want to be able to add an additional node to my token object after receiving it from Stripe to push it to the firebase database in a single write. In my project, I am pushing the token object to the database and then calling another write to add the additional node...

```
DatabaseReference tokenRef;
tokenRef = mRootRef.child("users").child(mUser.getUid()).child("payments").push();
tokenRef.setValue(token);
tokenRef.child("amount").setValue(500);
```

Ultimately, I want my database to look like this on a single write

[image]

Is there a way to merge the "amount" node to the token before passing it to firebase database?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a `Map` of all the key/values you want update at once and pass that Map to `setValue` for a single update.  This means you'll have to pull all the individual values out of `token`.

Alternatively, you can define a new property of `token` that contains the amount, and set it in there.  Or, if you can't modify whatever the class is for `token`, you can define a new class that contains all the data from `token`, and add amount to it, populate an instance of that class with all your data, and pass that to `setValue()`.

Comment: I definitely think the idea of creating a new model (eg. `CustomToken`) that inherits from Stripe's `Token`-class is the way to go here.  That way you can leverage the custom JSON serializer that's inside of the Stripe-Java library too.  If you don't have Stripe-Java, then I'd deserialize to a HashMap, add your key/value, then serialize back to JSON.